# Prove if $a \equiv c \pmod n$ and $b \equiv d \pmod n$ then $ab \equiv cd \pmod n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Prove if $a \equiv c \pmod{n}$ and $b \equiv d \pmod n$ then $ab \equiv cd \pmod{n}$.

I tried to use $(a-c)(b-d) = ab-ad-cb+cd$, but it seem doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to subtract and add the same thing:

$$ab-cd=ab-ad+ad-cd=\ldots$$

Comment: im stuck...a(b-d)+d(a-c),,,,,ank+dnl=np? k,l,p are integers

Comment: @puppylord: You know that $b-d=nk$ and $a-c=n\ell$ for some integers $k$ and $\ell$, so $ab-cd=ank+dn\ell=n(ak+d\ell)$. Is $ak+d\ell$ an integer?

Comment: Yes, I think.. how can you tell a and d are integers?

Comment: @puppylord: Context: the hypothesis that $a\equiv b\pmod n$ tells you that $a,b$, and $n$ are integers. (There are some rare situations in which that’s not true, but you’d know if you were in one of those contexts. At this point you probably haven’t seen congruence mod something even *defined* for non-integers.)

Comment: I got it now, thanks

Comment: @puppylord: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Congruence relation is transitive, and if $a\equiv b \mod(n)$, then $ax\equiv bx \mod n$. Play around.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to prove it is to use this fact:

$$a \equiv c \pmod n \implies n|a-c$$
$$b \equiv d \pmod n \implies n|b-d$$

Obviously then $n|b(a-c) + c(b-d)$

So we have: $n|ba - bc + bc - cd$

$$\implies n|ab - cd$$

Q.E.D.